# Validating div in body with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), how can I validate if a div exists in body of a HTML page or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the presence of any div:

```
if ($("div").length > 0) {
  // theres a div
}
```

Or a particular element with an ID:

```
if ($("#id").length > 0) {
  // it exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divExists = !!$('div').length;
```